# Background image scroll based on cursor for specific devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website that is a bit more interactive, I basically have an image in mind which I want to use for the background, but instead I want to make it so the image is zoomed in a bit and have it so that depending where you move the cursor it will move where you are looking on the image.

I am not sure if this makes sense, but I want to make it so this happens only on desktop or laptop type devices, and on mobile devices or tablets to just display the background normally.

Is this possible? If so I am not sure where to start, if anybody could help it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

Demo: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/
Git: https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom/

Then you can use media queries or JS to disable it for smaller devices.